# Can we denote a function without specifying its input variable(s)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, notation

I am in the process of writing my M.Sc. thesis. Coming from an ecology background, I have limited knowledge of mathematical notation. For the purpose of my project I define a differential equation system that I use as a base model upon which I build over the course of the paper, progressively adding complexity. For simplicity, let us say the base model would be:

$\frac{d_y}{d_t}=fy+\alpha$

In the simpler instance of the model, the function $f$ can be defined as a constant, e.g. $f=\beta$. However, in more complex instances it is implemented as a function, e.g., $f(y)=\beta y$, but the rest of the model structure remains identical. I do not want to re-expose the whole model every time complexity is built-in, but I want to make it clear that complexity will be built into $f$. Can $f$ be exposed as a function from the get-go? If so, what notation can I use that does not require to specify the input variables? What I mean is if the base model is defined as

$\frac{d_y}{d_t}=f(y)y+\alpha$

it induces confusion as to the structure of the simpler instances of the model, when $f=\beta$. I have tried presenting $f$, in the textual description of the equations system, as a function that represents, for instance, the growth rate, and that in the simplest instance of the model it is a constant, but readers have not picked it up and still wonder whether it is a function and, if so, why I do not use the $f()$ in the presentation of the base model.

Would anyone have suggestions as to improve the clarity of the model presentation with respect to the introduction of $f$?

Comment: Yes. $f(y)=\beta$ is perfectly fine. Here $f$ does not depend on $y$, but as you mentioned, the model will later be linear with respect to $y$.

Comment: Thank you for this precision Vladimir, I might take this route and be more specific in-text as to the purpose of the function and the use of implementations of different complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rely more on words than on making the symbol "$f$" carry so much weight. Perhaps you say something like

> Let $y$ represent [whatever it represents - perhaps population. And
>   choose a good name for the quantity, perhaps not $y$].
>
> I will study a model in which the rate of change of $y$ depends on
>   various conditions. In the simplest case $$ \frac{dy}{dt} =
>  \beta y + \alpha $$ for constants $\beta$ and $\alpha$. In later more
>   complicated models the differential equation will have the form $$
>  \frac{dy}{dt} = f(y,p) y + \alpha $$ where $f$ is a function of $y$
>   and of several other parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ethan. I think you are perfectly right and that a well worded description is much more valuable than a symbol left open to interpretation. The only issue here is the model is actually much more complex than the example given, and multiple functions like $f$ are initially implemented as constants. I want to avoid writing the model every time complexity is built in. But your answer made me think that I should be more specific in-text about this process, which might help readers follow our intent. Thank you for your help!